# setting up a dsn to a pervasive DB on Debian through pyodbc

Tags: python, odbc, debian, pervasive

I am trying to use python to pull data from a pervasive database, and put it in to a postgresql databse.

The postgresql connection is local and I can make that connection just fine.

However, the pervasive connection requires a dsn but I can not find the correct driver to use.

Can anybody shed some light on this problem that has been a huge problem for me these last few days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to install the Pervasive Linux client for the version of Pervasive you are using.  For example, if your Pervasive server is v11, you'd need the v11 client. If you've got v10, you need the v10 client. The v11 client s available at http://www.pervasive.com/database/Home/Products/PSQLv11.aspx and is available on Linux as an RPM or TAR. 
Once you've installed the client, you'll need to use the `dsnadd` command to add the Client DSN as [documented](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=uguide/unixsupp.08.12.html#68699).

Comment: Thank you for the help so far. I have downloaded the TAR file because I've heard RPMs should be avoided on Debain. I have extracted the files but, now I can not install the software.

I have tried:

*to cd to the software directory
*then to use ./configure.

The ./configure returns the error.
-bash ./configure: No such file or directory

I can not figure this out.

Comment: The installation is fully documented at http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=getstart/04nstunx.13.4.html.